# Generic function with AnyObject fails

Tags: function, generics, swift

I'm trying to use a generic function but i'm getting a segmentation fault.

I'd like to simplify the handling of my RestKit results by creating a generic function to handle it all. The function would essentially cast the array of the result to the desired type, and call the callback.

Here's the code

```
class func handleRestkitResult<T:AnyObject>(mappingResult:RKMappingResult!,callback:([T])->Void){
    var resultArray = mappingResult.array();

    if (resultArray is [T]){
        callback(resultArray as [T])
    }
}
```

Seems to have no errors. But when i run it, I get a segmentation default, and its the `handleRestkitResult<T:AnyObject>`.

Specifically the AnyObject part. If I remove it however, I get a warning that T does not conform to AnyObject.

Am I missing something here?

I'm know theres a way where I can pass the name of a class/type as a string, and do some sort of magic. But I'm still wondering whats going wrong here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `<T: Any>`?

Comment: I did. But since mappingResult.array() returns [AnyObject], I get an error on the if statement, saying "Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'"